# How can I draw a new joint in the hand by use mediapipe

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

first my goal is put the red dot on the middle of two joint(num is 1 , 5) then I calculate the place midpoint but i can't visualize my new point how can i visualize my new point and which library to make dot

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np

max_num_hands = 1

# MediaPipe hands model
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
hands = mp_hands.Hands(
    max_num_hands=max_num_hands,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5,
    min_tracking_confidence=0.5)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        continue

    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    result = hands.process(img)

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    if result.multi_hand_landmarks is not None:
        for res in result.multi_hand_landmarks:
            joint = np.zeros((22, 3))
            for j, lm in enumerate(res.landmark):
                joint[j] = [lm.x, lm.y, lm.z]
                
            joint[21, 0] = (joint[5,0] + joint[1,0])/2
            joint[21, 1] = (joint[5,1] + joint[1,1])/2
            joint[21, 2] = (joint[5,2] + joint[1,2])/2


            dot = (joint[21,0] , joint[21,1]) 
            dot_x = joint[21,0]
            dot_y = joint[21,1]

            cv2.circle(img, dot, 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)

            print(joint[21], joint[1], joint[5])




    cv2.imshow('Game', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

I want to make a new joint in the mediapipe library than I make joint [21]

then i want to display my new joint but I have some error

**error**

```
    cv2.circle(img, dot, 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'circle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

How can I make the dot on my new joint with opencv or other libraries in python.  I heard opencv can't make circle in 3D enviroment.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Sharing some images will help

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i add images!

Comment: exception comes from numpy code, so it's probably an issue of how you use numpy. error also suggests that you made a **typo**. the exception reproduces a line of code that does not exactly match the code you pasted in your question. did you even debug your code before asking? please review [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: if you just want to make a "new joint" as the midpoint of two existing ones, figure out the positions of the two, then calculate the midpoint, and you're done?

Comment: I calculate new mid point but i can't visualize new point on cam to use opencv how to visualize on my hand that new point ?

Comment: you're asking about multiple things. you should really review [ask]. the error in using cv.circle, you can search for that error and find solutions.

Comment: I read it and I delete other cv.circle